# Create new column in dataframe based on partial string matching other column

Tags: regex, string, r, match, partial

I have a dataframe with 2 columns `GL` and `GLDESC` and want to add a 3rd column called `KIND` based on some data that is inside of column `GLDESC`.

The dataframe is as follows:

```
      GL                             GLDESC
1 515100         Payroll-Indir Salary Labor
2 515900 Payroll-Indir Compensated Absences
3 532300                           Bulk Gas
4 539991                     Area Charge In
5 551000        Repairs & Maint-Spare Parts
6 551100                 Supplies-Operating
7 551300                        Consumables
```

For each row of the data table:

- If `GLDESC` contains the word `Payroll` anywhere in the string then I want `KIND` to be `Payroll`
- If `GLDESC` contains the word `Gas` anywhere in the string then I want `KIND` to be `Materials`
- In all other cases I want `KIND` to be `Other`

I looked for similar examples on stackoverflow but could not find any, also looked in `R` for dummies on switch, grep, apply and regular expressions to try and match only part of the `GLDESC` column and then fill the `KIND` column with the kind of account but was unable to make it work.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since you have only two conditions, you can use a nested `ifelse`:

```
#random data; it wasn't easy to copy-paste yours  
DF <- data.frame(GL = sample(10), GLDESC = paste(sample(letters, 10), 
  c("gas", "payroll12", "GaSer", "asdf", "qweaa", "PayROll-12", 
     "asdfg", "GAS--2", "fghfgh", "qweee"), sample(letters, 10), sep = " "))

DF$KIND <- ifelse(grepl("gas", DF$GLDESC, ignore.case = T), "Materials", 
         ifelse(grepl("payroll", DF$GLDESC, ignore.case = T), "Payroll", "Other"))

DF
#   GL         GLDESC      KIND
#1   8        e gas l Materials
#2   1  c payroll12 y   Payroll
#3  10      m GaSer v Materials
#4   6       t asdf n     Other
#5   2      w qweaa t     Other
#6   4 r PayROll-12 q   Payroll
#7   9      n asdfg a     Other
#8   5     d GAS--2 w Materials
#9   7     s fghfgh e     Other
#10  3      g qweee k     Other
```

**EDIT** *10/3/2016* *(..after receiving more attention than expected)*

A possible solution to deal with more patterns could be to iterate over all patterns and, whenever there is match, progressively reduce the amount of comparisons:

```
ff = function(x, patterns, replacements = patterns, fill = NA, ...)
{
    stopifnot(length(patterns) == length(replacements))

    ans = rep_len(as.character(fill), length(x))    
    empty = seq_along(x)

    for(i in seq_along(patterns)) {
        greps = grepl(patterns[[i]], x[empty], ...)
        ans[empty[greps]] = replacements[[i]]  
        empty = empty[!greps]
    }

    return(ans)
}

ff(DF$GLDESC, c("gas", "payroll"), c("Materials", "Payroll"), "Other", ignore.case = TRUE)
# [1] "Materials" "Payroll"   "Materials" "Other"     "Other"     "Payroll"   "Other"     "Materials" "Other"     "Other"

ff(c("pat1a pat2", "pat1a pat1b", "pat3", "pat4"), 
   c("pat1a|pat1b", "pat2", "pat3"), 
   c("1", "2", "3"), fill = "empty")
#[1] "1"     "1"     "3"     "empty"

ff(c("pat1a pat2", "pat1a pat1b", "pat3", "pat4"), 
   c("pat2", "pat1a|pat1b", "pat3"), 
   c("2", "1", "3"), fill = "empty")
#[1] "2"     "1"     "3"     "empty"
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for sharing this regex, its very useful. If we were to define a second variable other than `kind` i.e I want another string `labor` to be replaced with `xyz` in a new variable `new` then do we have to run the regex individually for each such new variable. Also you did not define `kind` in the latest iterative function. Thanks!

Comment: @ManasiShah : You mean something like `DF$new = ff(DF$GLDESC, "labor", "xyz", "Other", ignore.case = TRUE)`? The function (`ff`) at the end, is a more general one and its result can be used to assign back to the "data.frame" as a second step. Or am I missing your point?

Answer (score 1):

I personally like matching by index. You can loop `grep` over your new labels, in order to get the indices of your partial matches, then use this with a lookup table to simply reassign the values.

If you wanna create new labels, use a named vector.

```r
DF <- data.frame(GL = sample(10), GLDESC = paste(sample(letters, 10),
  c(
    "gas", "payroll12", "GaSer", "asdf", "qweaa", "PayROll-12",
    "asdfg", "GAS--2", "fghfgh", "qweee"
  ), sample(letters, 10),
  sep = " "
))


lu <- stack(sapply(c(Material = "gas", Payroll = "payroll"), grep, x = DF$GLDESC, ignore.case = TRUE))

DF$KIND <- DF$GLDESC
DF$KIND[lu$values] <- as.character(lu$ind)
DF$KIND[-lu$values] <- "Other"

DF
#>    GL         GLDESC     KIND
#> 1   6        x gas f Material
#> 2   3  t payroll12 q  Payroll
#> 3   5      a GaSer h Material
#> 4   4       s asdf x    Other
#> 5   1      m qweaa y    Other
#> 6  10 y PayROll-12 r  Payroll
#> 7   7      g asdfg a    Other
#> 8   2     k GAS--2 i Material
#> 9   9     e fghfgh j    Other
#> 10  8      l qweee p    Other
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>