# partial matching in r- multiple matches

Tags: regex, r, string, match, grepl

I am leveraging the code below to partial match with 1 match but have a follow up question: supposed we had an additional criteria for fish, and we wanted "dog fish" to be categorized as both fish and canine. Is this possible?

```
d<-data.frame(name=c("brown cat", "blue cat", "big lion", "tall tiger", 
                 "black panther", "short cat", "red bird",
                 "short bird stuffed", "big eagle", "bad sparrow",
                 "dog fish", "head dog", "brown yorkie",
                 "lab short bulldog"), label=1:14)
```

## Define the regexes at the beginning of the code

```
regexes <- list(c("(cat|lion|tiger|panther)","feline"),
            c("(bird|eagle|sparrow)","avian"),
            c("(dog|yorkie|bulldog)","canine"))
```

## Create a vector, the same length as the df

```
output_vector <- character(nrow(d))
```

## For each regex..

```
for(i in seq_along(regexes)){

#Grep through d$name, and when you find matches, insert the relevant 'tag' into
#The output vector
output_vector[grepl(x = d$name, pattern = regexes[[i]][1])] <- regexes[[i]][2]}
```

## Insert that now-filled output vector into the dataframe

```
d$species <- output_vector
```

## Desired Output

```
#                 name label species
#1           brown cat     1  feline
#2            blue cat     2  feline
#3            big lion     3  feline
#4          tall tiger     4  feline
#5       black panther     5  feline
#6           short cat     6  feline
#7            red bird     7   avian
#8  short bird stuffed     8   avian
#9           big eagle     9   avian
#10        bad sparrow    10   avian
#11           dog fish    11  canine, fish
#12           head dog    12  canine
#13       brown yorkie    13  canine
#14  lab short bulldog    14  canine
```

The original stack overflow question is here: [partial string matching r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949300/partial-string-matching-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do through a cross join.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

key = data_frame(partial = c("cat", "lion", "tiger", "panther",
                             "bird", "eagle", "sparrow",
                             "dog", "yorkie", "bulldog"),
                  category = c("feline", "feline", "feline", "feline",
                               "avian", "avian", "avian",
                               "canine", "canine", "canine"))

d %>%
  merge(key) %>%
  filter(name %>% stri_detect_fixed(partial) )
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just popped an aggregate at the end of this and it gave me EXACTLY what I wanted!