# Add new columns to a data frame by separating character strings in an existing column

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I want to add a new column to a `data.frame` based on the last entry in a string so that I can do regression analysis. In particular, I am trying to extract information from the `Fertiliser` variable which contains information on the amount of three different types of fertiliser, separated by hyphens. For instance: `0-0-0` or `30-10-2700` are viable. The last portion of the string is what I need to capture e.g. `x-y-z` I need `z`.

I tried but was not able to adapt the answer here [How to create new column in dataframe based on partial string matching other column in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747384/how-to-create-new-column-in-dataframe-based-on-partial-string-matching-other-col) to this case.

More complete example of the data:

```
    Fertiliser millet_biomass millet_yield
 1:      0-0-0       2659.608     710.6942
 2:    0-0-100       2701.044     718.1154
 3:   0-0-2700       3415.879     804.0360
 4:    0-0-300       2781.639     730.5943
 5:    0-0-900       2997.173     760.0136
 6:     12-4-0       3703.255     772.1719
 7:   12-4-100       3720.247     773.1759
 8:  12-4-2700       3950.189     788.6133
 9:   12-4-300       3751.400     775.1368
10:   12-4-900       3826.693     780.2623
11:    30-10-0       4180.323     798.2134
12:  30-10-100       4184.229     798.4918
13: 30-10-2700       4217.044     800.9312
14:  30-10-300       4187.014     798.6570
15:  30-10-900       4194.873     799.2085
16:      6-2-0       3296.274     765.8496
17:    6-2-100       3326.844     767.6693
18:   6-2-2700       3772.058     785.4535
19:    6-2-300       3381.152     760.7330
20:    6-2-900       3517.515     768.3018
21:    90-30-0       4542.924     831.2832
22:  90-30-100       4543.036     831.3983
23: 90-30-2700       4545.037     831.3227
24:  90-30-300       4543.240     831.3921
25:  90-30-900       4543.733     831.3727
```

Thus, there are five patterns `-0$`, `-100$`, `-300$`, `-900$`, `2700$`, which need to be replaced by `0`, `100`, `300`, `900`, `2700`

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want to do? Let's take a snippet of data:

```
Fertiliser <- c("0-0-0", "0-0-100", "0-0-2700", "0-0-300")
millet_yield <- c(710, 718, 804, 730)
df <- data.frame(Fertiliser, millet_yield)
```

`df` looks like this:

```
   Fertiliser millet_yield
#1      0-0-0          710
#2    0-0-100          718
#3   0-0-2700          804
#4    0-0-300          730
```

Using `separate()` from the `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% separate(Fertiliser, into=(c("F1", "F2", "Manure")), sep="-", convert=T)

   F1 F2 Manure millet_yield
#1  0  0      0          710
#2  0  0    100          718
#3  0  0   2700          804
#4  0  0    300          730
```

`convert=T` makes sure the character strings become numeric. Now you can run a regression on your data.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need. But the columns are not added to the data.frame. How can I do it? I am not used to the operator %>%

Comment: Oh, you mean you wanted to keep the original column? Then it's `df %>% separate(Fertiliser, into=(c("F1", "F2", "Manure")), sep="-", convert=T, remove=F)`. All other columns will be kept. The operator `%>%` is just for chaining functions together in `tidyr` and `dplyr`.

Comment: No no, the original column is not necessary. The result shows perfect in the console, but not in the data.frame (Environment->Data). It still displays the same variables as before running the line :S

Comment: `df2 <- df %>% separate(Fertiliser, into=(c("F1", "F2", "Manure")), sep="-", convert=T)`

Answer (score 0):

We can extract the last numbers with `stri_extract_last` from `stringi`.  As the dataset is a already a `data.table`, can use the `data.table` methods to assign (`:=`) a new column.

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)
setDT(df1)[, Manure := as.numeric(stri_extract_last_regex(Fertiliser, "\\d+"))]
head(df1)
#   Fertiliser millet_biomass millet_yield Manure
#1:      0-0-0       2659.608     710.6942      0
#2:    0-0-100       2701.044     718.1154    100
#3:   0-0-2700       3415.879     804.0360   2700
#4:    0-0-300       2781.639     730.5943    300
#5:    0-0-900       2997.173     760.0136    900
#6:     12-4-0       3703.255     772.1719      0
```

---

Or a `base R` option is

```
df1$Manure <- as.numeric(sub(".*-", "", df1$Fertiliser))
```

Comment: It works. I really like this style. Can we also use stringi to create a new column with only certain words within a character? i.e, from a column with values "Millet high SOC"; "Millet medium SOC" and "Millet low SOC" I want to create a new column which either contain "high", medium" or "low"

Comment: @M.Jimenez  You could use `setDT(df1)[, NewCol := stri_extract(Col, regex="(?<=\\s)\\w+")]`

Comment: Concise and effective. Thank you

Comment: Oh thank you. I didn't know I could choose only one. Indeed all have being good and I've tried to vote for all :-). I've used your solution in combination with another one.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with `sub`, removing everything up to and including the last hyphen character:

```
transform(x, Fertiliser = sub('.*-', '', Fertiliser))
##     Fertiliser millet_biomass millet_yield
## 1:           0       2659.608     710.6942
## 2:         100       2701.044     718.1154
## 3:        2700       3415.879     804.0360
## 4:         300       2781.639     730.5943
```

...

Here, the `.*` is greedy, so it matches as much as possible before matching the final `-` character.

You can also rename the resulting column, rather than replacing `Fertiliser`:

```
 transform(x, Quantity = sub('.*-', '', Fertiliser))
```