# Creating new column based on string values from another column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in r with a column which is a big string. I want to use that string to create a new column with specific values.

This is the sample dataframe:

```
dom <- data.frame(
  Site = c("alpha", "beta", "charlie", "delta"),
  Banner = c("testing_Watermelon -DPI_300x250 v2"   , "notest_Vanilla Latte-DPI_300x250 v2" , "bottle :15s","aaaa vvvv cccc Build_Mobile_320x480")
)
```

Now if the column Banner has string containing `Watermelon` or `Vanilla` then the new column `label` should have values only `Watermelon` or `Vanilla` else `Default`. Below is what the expected dataframe should be like.

How can I use `grep` or anything else to have multiple conditions in that?

```
dom_output <- data.frame(
  Site = c("alpha", "beta", "charlie", "delta"),
  Banner = c("testing_Watermelon -bbb_300x250 v2"   , "notest_Orange aaa_300x250 v2"    , "bottle :15s","aaaa vvvv cccc 320x480"),
  label  = c("Watermelon","Vanilla","Default","Default")
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create new column in dataframe based on partial string matching other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747384/create-new-column-in-dataframe-based-on-partial-string-matching-other-column)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(stringr)
dom$label = str_extract(dom$Banner, "Watermelon|Vanilla")
dom$label[is.na(dom$label)] <- "Default"
dom
#      Site                              Banner      label
# 1   alpha  testing_Watermelon -DPI_300x250 v2 Watermelon
# 2    beta notest_Vanilla Latte-DPI_300x250 v2    Vanilla
# 3 charlie                         bottle :15s    Default
# 4   delta aaaa vvvv cccc Build_Mobile_320x480    Default
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using Base R:

```r
#Sample data:
dom <- data.frame(
  Site = c("alpha", "beta", "charlie", "delta"),
  Banner = c("testing_Watermelon -DPI_300x250 v2"   , "notest_Vanilla Latte-DPI_300x250 v2" , "bottle :15s","aaaa vvvv cccc Build_Mobile_320x480")
)


dom$label <- ifelse(grepl("watermelon", dom$Banner, ignore.case = T), "Watermelon",
                    ifelse(grepl("vanilla", dom$Banner, ignore.case = T), "Vanilla", "Default"))
```

Answer (score 0):

One `base R` possibility could be:

```
labels <- paste(c("Watermelon", "Orange"), collapse = "|")

dom$label <- sapply(regmatches(dom$Banner, regexec(labels, dom$Banner)), "[", 1)
dom$label[is.na(dom$label)] <- "Default"

     Site                              Banner      label
1   alpha  testing_Watermelon -DPI_300x250 v2 Watermelon
2    beta  notest_Orange Latte-DPI_300x250 v2     Orange
3 charlie                         bottle :15s    Default
4   delta aaaa vvvv cccc Build_Mobile_320x480    Default
```

The same could be used also by `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
dom %>%
 mutate(label = sapply(regmatches(Banner, regexec(labels, Banner)), "[", 1),
        label = replace_na(label, "Default"))
```

Sample data:

```
dom <- data.frame(
 Site = c("alpha", "beta", "charlie", "delta"),
 Banner = c("testing_Watermelon -DPI_300x250 v2"   , "notest_Orange Latte-DPI_300x250 v2" , "bottle :15s","aaaa vvvv cccc Build_Mobile_320x480")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

dom %>% mutate(label = case_when(stri_detect_fixed(Banner, "Watermelon") ~ "Watermelon",
                                 stri_detect_fixed(Banner, "Vanilla")    ~ "Vanilla",
                                                                   TRUE  ~ "Default"))
#>      Site                              Banner          label
#> 1   alpha  testing_Watermelon -DPI_300x250 v2     Watermelon
#> 2    beta notest_Vanilla Latte-DPI_300x250 v2        Vanilla
#> 3 charlie                         bottle :15s        Default
#> 4   delta aaaa vvvv cccc Build_Mobile_320x480        Default
```

***Data:***

```r
dom <- data.frame(Site = c("alpha", "beta", "charlie", "delta"),
                  Banner = c("testing_Watermelon -DPI_300x250 v2",
                             "notest_Vanilla Latte-DPI_300x250 v2",
                             "bottle :15s",
                             "aaaa vvvv cccc Build_Mobile_320x480"))
```